# How to "fix" code search in VS2022 V17.8? (I want the old search back)

Tags: visual-studio

For years when I click CTL+, I can search for a file and if I most of it's name then it's the first item in the list and I can hit enter and I'm looking at the code.

But just recently (probably my upgrade to VS 17.8) this same process yields stupid results.

Take for example the results below.  I typed in blog-post and I'm wanting to open the blog-post.cshtml file.  Yet the first result is for a post object in signalr.js, and the second result is also very unexpected.  Neither of the first two results contain the phrase I have typed in.  My result is the 3rd one.

It knows that only the third one contains what I typed, and even highlights the text on the third one.  Why in the world isn't that result in the first result as it was in the past?

[image]

So for years, I could type `CTL+,` then type part of the file name, `blog-post` in this case, and hit return and I'd be off to coding.  Now I need to `CTL+,` then type part of the file name, THEN down arrow a few times past results that don't contain the phrase I typed in, and then I can finally hit return to get my file.

It may sound like a minor thing.  But when a person searches for code hundreds (maybe thousands) of times a day, this change is a huge time waste.

This change appears to be part of some new "improved" search functionality.  Maybe AI-based?  It's horrible.

Does anyone know how to disable this and get back to the way it used to work?